# vba Access print

Tags: vba, printing

I am using vba to make a program.
I am trying to make a print function. When I click one button, it should be printed directly. Does it neccessary to make a Report form for this one? I am little bit confusing.

How can I make a print function in Access?
Any comments would be greatly thankful!
(It would be nice if you can share your source code)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [DoCmd.PrintOut method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/docmd-printout-method-access), which is used to print the active object in the open database. You can print datasheets, reports, forms, data access pages, and modules.

```
DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 1, 4, , 2
```